# How to get the ROWID or row-order of a sorted table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, count, sql-update, sql-order-by, window-functions

I need to sort a given table by one attribute and then store the order of this sorted table in one column of this table in SQLite. How can this be done?

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE t0 (name TEXT, sortId INT)
INSERT INTO t0 VALUES ('C', NULL)
INSERT INTO t0 VALUES ('A', NULL)
INSERT INTO t0 VALUES ('B', NULL)
```

Now I need to sort that table by attribute "name" and store the index of the sorted rows via UPDATE-command in column "sortId". The result should look like this:

```
name sortId
---- ------
C         3
A         1
B         2
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in a `CTE` to get the ranking of each row and join it to the table in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rn FROM t0)
UPDATE t0
SET sortId = cte.rn
FROM cte
WHERE cte.name = t0.name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5cUhm4ng).

For older versions of SQLite without support of the `UPDATE...FROM` syntax or even window functions you can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE t0
SET sortId = (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM t0 AS t WHERE t.name < t0.name);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TrdrjXv3).

Comment: For any reason I cannot run this in Powershell via PPSQLite module. It throws an error. I also reoved the id-colun from the sample, because its a bit misleading.

Comment: @Carsten check your version of SQLite with: `select sqlite_version();`

Comment: version is 3.8.8.3

Comment: @Carsten your version is more than 8 years old. The current version of SQLite is 3.41.0: https://sqlite.org/changes.html I will edit my answer with a query that works in your version but only if name is unique. Is it?

Comment: @fopas That is the version that comes with the PSQLite module. I used that one because its the easiest way to write SQLite commands in PS. Yes, name is unique and sortId is the order of rows after the sort. Not based on the id-column I had in my initial version of the question.

Comment: @Carsten see my 2nd query.